# understanding the use of typeof

Tags: wordpress, typeof

I am trying to resolve a issue in wordpress and being a noob, i was stumped when faced with the following code (the last part in bold which consists of typeof). Can anyone explain it to me in simple english?

```
<input id="et_pb_number" type="text" class="regular-text" value="<%= typeof( et_pb_number ) !== 'undefined' ?  et_pb_number : '' %>" />
```

From my understanding, does it mean that something (assuming javascript) will check the type of the variable (et_pb_number) and see if it is undefined, and then what happen next?

what should i do if i don't want it to check the type of the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the surrounding part is not directly related to typeof. It's the [Ternary Operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#JavaScript) `expression ? when-true : when-false`

These two are exactly the same:

```
// ternary form
var test = typeof( et_pb_number ) !== 'undefined' ?  et_pb_number : '';
console.log(test);


// if else block form
var test;
if (typeof et_pb_number !== 'undefined') {
    test = et_pb_number;
} else {
    test = "";
}
console.log(test);
```

The Ternary operator exists in many programming languages and can technically used exactly as if/else - but be careful! It is (as you experienced yourself) sometimes hard to read. One convention is, to *only* use it to return one or the other based on some condition (it's used in that way in your example). In a manner of speaking: this should (usually) only be used if it has no side-effects other than returning one value.

You could technically totally do this, but i would not recommend it (again: for understandability reasons. Technically it's just fine):

```
// don't do this (unless you have a really really really good reason.
var someValue = true;
someValue ? $('body').html('Hello') : $('body').html('World')
```

That example would change the outside world directly.